# How to create template longtable/datatool code?

Tags: macros, datatool

Consider the MWE below (TexLive '15, pdflatex). I have multiple datafiles which need to be displayed in different tables. Currently I have copied table code like MWE multiple times.

**Q1:** But, what is **the best (least side effects) way** so I can write (here we pass the filename, caption, label):

```
\createMyTable(dbset1,'data1.csv',The Caption,The caption (continued),tab:thelabel1)
```

**Q2:** Now even more advanced. Assume I have now a file with a different structure (data3.csv in the MWE below with 2 columns), is it even possible to parameterize the columns (eg **Latex code as string, interpreted on the fly**), the assignments and output? So:

```
\createMyTable(dbset1,'data3.csv',p{1cm}p{1cm},\textbf{Col1}&\textbf{Col2},"Col1=col1,Col2=col2","\Col1&\Col2", Caption,The caption (continued),tab:thelabel1)
```

**MWE:**

```
\begin{filecontents}{data1.csv}
col1
1
2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.csv}
col1
3
4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data3.csv}
col1,col2
5,6
7,8
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

% START FUNCTION createMyTable(dbset1,'data1.csv',The Caption,The caption (continued),tab:thelabel1)

\DTLloaddb{dbset1}{data1.csv}

\afterpage{%
        \newgeometry{twoside=false,vmargin={1cm,1cm},hmargin={1cm,3cm}}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \centering % Center table
        \vspace{0pt}
        \begin{singlespacing}
\begin{longtable}[c]{p{1cm}}
 \caption{The Caption}
 \label{tab:thelabel}\tabularnewline
 \textbf{Col1}\tabularnewline
 \midrule
 \endfirsthead
 \caption{The Caption (Continued)}\tabularnewline
  \textbf{Col1}\tabularnewline
 \midrule
 \endhead
 \bottomrule
 \multicolumn{1}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page...}}
 \endfoot
 \bottomrule
 \endlastfoot
 \DTLforeach*{dbset1}{\TheCol=col1}%
 {\DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}\TheCol}%
\end{longtable}
    \end{singlespacing}
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage
}
\restoregeometry

% END FUNCTION

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: Even if it is possible, it is a bad idea to try to save time by hiing everything in macros. Though you might not have noticed it yet, about two thirds of your tables are *special* and can't be dealt with the interface provided. You will want to change stuff, making the macro more and more complicated, which will lead to a huge loss of time. Eperience speaking.